# SQL: get a value from a column that might be in another table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, refactoring, multiple-columns

I am doing a refactor in work and I moved a column from one table to the other.

There is a table that represents a shelf `static.connected_shelf` (with iot devices on it), 
and there is a table that represents devices `static.iot_devices`.

Now, there are new devices that are not installed on shelves, and therefore, the attribute `iot_device_type_fk` has to be moved from `static.connected_shelf` to `static.iot_devices`.

To prevent a race condition when I try to reach this attribute, I need to modify my queries, so when it searches for the device type in `static.iot_devices` but the column does not exist there (the refactor did not happen yet in that environment), the test will not fail, but go back to `static.connected_shelf` and get the value from there.

Here is an example of a very simple query:

```
    query = """SELECT c.pk connected_shelf_fk, i.iot_device_type_fk  device_type_fk, i.pk device_fk
               FROM static.connected_shelf c
               JOIN static.iot_devices i ON c.pk = i.connected_shelf_fk
               WHERE i.pk = %(device_id)s"""
    cursor.execute(query, {'device_id': device_id})
```

So here, I already modify the query so it looks for `iot_device_type_fk` in `static.iot_devices`. how can I make sure that if this column does not exist in that table, I will get it from `static.connected_shelf`?

Comment: You should only have this information in one column.  This is not a normalized design.  This race condition will come to grief.

Comment: @duffymo you are correct. in the end, the column will be only in one table, but until everything around it is aligned, it is not possible to simply delete it from the old table.

Comment: Don't delete.  Populate the new column, update the queries, and let it go to prod in the new state.  Remove the old data when you confirm that all is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the value to be in *both* tables, with `NULL` values in the tables where the values have not been assigned.  If so:

```
SELECT c.pk as connected_shelf_fk,
       COALESCE(i.iot_device_type_fk, c.connected_shelf) as iot_device_type_fk,
       i.pk as device_fk,
FROM static.connected_shelf c JOIN
     static.iot_devices i
     ON c.pk = i.connected_shelf_fk
WHERE i.pk = %(device_id)s
```

If the column really doesn't exist, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT c.pk as connected_shelf_fk,
       (SELECT iot_device_type_fk  -- no alias!
        FROM static.iot_devices i2
        WHERE i2.pk = i.pk
       ) as iot_device_type_fk,
       i.pk as device_fk,
FROM static.connected_shelf c JOIN
     static.iot_devices i
     ON c.pk = i.connected_shelf_fk
WHERE i.pk = %(device_id)s
```

The subquery will look for `iot_device_type_fk` first in `iot_devices` and then in `connected_shelf`.

Comment: Thanks but that is not right. if I run this in an environment that has not been refactored yet, the column will not exist in iot_device.
If I run it in an environment that was refactored already, the column will not exist in connected_shelf.

Comment: I need to make sure the tests will not fail in all of the environments until the refactoring is complete.

Comment: You should accept this answer.  Better than a race condition.